# How to prove $\cos(\frac{B-C}2)\ge \sqrt{\frac{2r}{R}}$?

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

For any triangle $ABC$, prove that:
$$\cos(\frac{B-C}2)\ge \sqrt{\frac{2r}{R}}$$

I have tried many approaches but none seems to work. I noted that $\cos(\frac{B-C}2)=\frac{AM}{2R}$, where $M$ is point of intersection of the circumcircle and bisector of $\angle A$, but it wasn't much helpful. Although, Euler's inequality seems to be helpful, it isn't. And expanding out $\cos(\frac{B-C}2)$ gets very complicated.

Does anyone have some elegant methods?

Comment: What is $r$, and $R$?

Comment: @Jika Inradius and circumradius respectively, of course.

Comment: Remember the inscribed circle center goes through the angle bisectors (and hence the $\frac{1}{2}$) in the angle.

Comment: @ja72 Yes, I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that $$\frac{r}{4R}= \sin \frac{A}{2}\cdot\sin \frac{B}{2}\cdot\sin \frac{C}{2}.$$
and consequently$$\frac{2r}{R}= 8\sin \frac{A}{2}\cdot\sin \frac{B}{2}\cdot\sin \frac{C}{2}.$$
$$\cos \frac{B-C}{2}\geq\sqrt{\frac{2r}{R}}\Leftrightarrow\cos^2 \frac{B-C}{2}\geq\frac{2r}{R}\Leftrightarrow\cos^2 \frac{B-C}{2}\geq 8\sin \frac{A}{2}\cdot\sin \frac{B}{2}\cdot\sin \frac{C}{2}\Leftrightarrow\cos^2 \frac{B-C}{2}\geq 4\sin \frac{A}{2}(\cos \frac{B-C}{2}-\cos \frac{B+C}{2})\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\cos^2 \frac{B-C}{2}\geq 4\sin \frac{A}{2}(\cos \frac{B-C}{2}-\sin \frac{A}{2})\Leftrightarrow(\cos \frac{B-C}{2}-\sin \frac{A}{2})^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: Great answer! But I think there should be $(\cos \frac{B-C}{2}-2\sin \frac{A}{2})^2\geq 0$ at the end :)